# What's the difference between buildscript and allprojects in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

On a multi-project gradle build, can someone tell me what exactly is the difference between the "allprojects" section and the "buildscript" one?  Both have a `repositories` and `dependencies` task. Is `allprojects` for my project? What about `buildscript`?

```
buildscript {  
     repositories {
         ...
     }
     dependencies {
         ...
     }
}
```

and

```
allprojects(subprojects) { 
     repositories {
         ...
     }
     dependencies {
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The "`buildscript`" configuration section is for gradle itself (i.e. changes to how gradle is able to perform the build).  So this section will usually include the Android Gradle plugin.

The "`allprojects`" section is for the modules being built by Gradle.

Oftentimes the repository section is the same for both, since both will get their dependencies from jcenter usually (or maybe maven central).  But the "dependencies" section will be different.

Usually the "dependencies" section for "allprojects" is empty since the dependencies for each module are unique and will be in the "build.gradle" file within each of the modules.  However, if all of the modules shared the same dependencies then they could be listed here.

Comment: Do we have to specify gradle version?

Comment: user:6998684  The version of gradle applies to the entire project and is declared in a file that's a bit hidden.  Look in "./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties"

Comment: Hello, question: Can I use *one* repositories or dependencies property outside of the scope/closures of both *for* both or do they both have to be inside the scope of either `buildscript` or `allprojects`? And does the `classpath` property inside the `buildscript` property have an effect on a `dependencyManagement` property outside of the `buildscript` property? Thanks

Answer (score 28):

TL;DR: `buildscript` helps find plugins, `allprojects` applies to all projects

---

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#applyPluginBuildscript says

> Binary plugins that have been published as external jar files can be added to a project by adding the plugin to the build script classpath and then applying the plugin.

So you need `buildscript` for gradle to find the plugins, [as](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#plugins)

> Gradle at its core intentionally provides very little for real world automation. All of the useful features, like the ability to compile Java code, are added by plugins. Plugins add new tasks (e.g. JavaCompile), domain objects (e.g. SourceSet), conventions (e.g. Java source is located at src/main/java) as well as extending core objects and objects from other plugins.

[Concerning `allprojects`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:defining_common_behavior):

> The Project API provides a property `allprojects` which returns a list with the current project and all its subprojects underneath it. If you call `allprojects` with a closure, the statements of the closure are delegated to the projects associated with `allprojects`.

Comment: To me, as beginner in android ecosystem, this means nothing. Where do we need to put our dependencies? Can we delete that "buildscript"?

Comment: @MartinBerger: put your dependencies in the module's `build.gradle`, not the `build.gradle` that is one directory above, which this question deals with