# Spring boot failing to resolve spring-boot-dependencies using gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

The *build.gradle.kts* file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    val springBootVersion by extra("2.1.3.RELEASE")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
    }
}

plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.3.RELEASE"
}

apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
```

The error message is this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.3.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
 Required by:
     project :
```

The gradle version is:

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.18.7-100.fc27.x86_64 amd64
```

The groovy dsl seems to work fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `buildscript` section, which is useless, and specify the repositories *inside* the build:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.3.RELEASE"
}

apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! Why would they insist in using the _bulidScript_ section in the documentation?

Comment: Where do "they" do that? I don't see any buildscript here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I had to add mavenCentral in the *allProjects* section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158971/whats-the-difference-between-buildscript-and-allprojects-in-build-gradle) about buildscript vs allprojects  can help clarify.