# Where do I add repositories in my root-level build.gradle file?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies, android-studio-bumblebee

Recently, I updated my Android Studio to Bumblebee(stable version) that was released around 2 weeks back. The structure of the build.gradle(root-level) file seems to have changed a lot since the last version.

I am facing issue in adding dependencies in the root-level build.gradle file.

Here is what I want to add.[image]

in the build.gradle file

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

settings.gradle instead of build.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
      // ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

this way you dont need to use the build.gradle instead use the settings.gradle, these way it worked for me in Android Studio   Bumblebee

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `buildscript` instead of `allprojects`. Found question in stackoverflow which explain difference between buildscript and allprojects [What's the difference between buildscript and allprojects in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158971/whats-the-difference-between-buildscript-and-allprojects-in-build-gradle)
So I would suggest to try:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: Yeah, it helped but the problem was in the dependency itself, what I was trying to use was not supported for AndroidX but nevertheless thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep your buildscript repositories at the top of your project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // HERE
    }
}

plugins {
    // ...
}
```

2. Move your allprojects repositories to `settings.gradle` file:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        // HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**1.instead of openping build.gradle just open the setting.gradle and just the stuff there..it will working properly**


pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        //..... just add here
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```