# Firebase setup missing plugins on Root-level (project-level) Gradle file (<project>/build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

When I gointo to setup my firebase project and I followed firebase introductions, they say [image]
but I cannot find like this plugins in my root level build.gradle file. bellow code is my build.gradle file,

[image]

Have any solotion add it,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm trying to [this]([Where do I add repositories in my root-level build.gradle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095095/where-do-i-add-repositories-in-my-root-level-build-gradle-file) this solutions) but it's not work to me.

When I add into the as bellow like it give error,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {

    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

it was give error like this,

Build file 'E:\Flutter\Firebase\android\build.gradle' line: 17

Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.4.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add google service plugin in your `buildscript`'s `dependencies` like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // new added
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
}
```